# Reeating task every specified duration with background worker in .net?

Tags: android, vb.net, android-asynctask, backgroundworker

I have a win form, where I have a block of code which keeps checking for entry in database, every say 2mins. Now I want to avoid using timer control, for performance reason; can the same be achieved using background worker?

Comment: what do you mean by "avoid timer control for performance reason" ? there are timer classes which run on separate threads...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new thread and than

```
While True 
  CallTheDB()
  Thread.Sleep(120000)
End While
```